# Redirecting adsense not approved website to Adsense approved Website?

Tags: redirects, google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I have 2 websites , one is getting good traffic and another not much. Can I get approval for the low traffic-website and redirect the high traffic website to the low- traffic website?

I don't intend to apply for adsense the high traffic website.

Comment: Is the content on the high traffic website inconsistent with the [Google publisher policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9335564)?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It was disapproved by adsense due to sharing of media.

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller You always reply to most questions and make this community a better place,

Comment: If I place media sharing links in a website dynamically, like in a plugin , and that content is displayed only when a user visits, still  my website will be rejected?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get approved on one of your websites, it would be possible to redirect the other website to it and show its content there with ads.

However, just because a website is approve for AdSense, doesn't mean that it will stay that way.  Your AdSense approval can be revoked for violating the terms of service.   You can only display ads on pages that are compliant with the AdSense terms of service if you want to get paid and continue using AdSense.

I'm not sure what "sharing media" means.  Possibly allowing users to upload copyright material for others to download?    I guess it doesn't matter. If it is against the AdSense terms of service, you can't show AdSense ads on pages that have that content.  It doesn't matter if the content is "dynamic" or not.